# grid.table() conditional formatting in R

Tags: r

---

I was looking at this [link](http://code.google.com/p/gridextra/wiki/tableGrob), that produces a grid table and does text formatting. Is there any way I can do conditional formatting?
For e.g.

1. Set background color based on the value
2. Show negative values as red and blue otherwise

---

```
source("http://gridextra.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/inst/tableGrob2.r")
library(grid)

tc  = textConnection("
 carat   VeryLongWordIndeed color clarity depth
14513  1.35 Ideal     J     VS2  61.4
28685  0.30  Good     G    VVS1  64.0
50368  0.75 Ideal     F     SI2  59.2")
d = read.table(tc,head=T)
close(tc)
grid.newpage()
g = grid.table2(d)
grid.gedit(paste("cells-fill-",1,2,sep=""), gp=gpar(fill="red"))
```

This works as expected. But if you have more than 10 rows, it doesn't. It colors more than one cell. For e.g.

```
d<-do.call("rbind", replicate(10, d, simplify = FALSE))
grid.newpage()
g = grid.table2(d)
grid.gedit(paste("cells-fill-",1,2,sep=""), gp=gpar(fill="red"))
```

How to avoid this?

Comment: I do wonder if one could create a test and feed a result to the `fill` grid parameter. Why not construct a simple test case and see if anyone is up to the challenge?

Comment: Check out the third-from-last comment in the link you supplied, which addresses the question of whether individual cells can be highlighted.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien indeed, few people seem to have seen this, I'll add it as an answer even if it is suboptimal

Answer (score 3):

There was a way in earlier versions of grid.table; unfortunately it is not compatible with some of the later features. I have placed a copy of the code in [`inst/tableGrob2.r`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baptiste/gridextra/master/inst/test/tableGrob2.r). You can try,

```
library(grid)

 tc  = textConnection("
     carat   VeryLongWordIndeed color clarity depth
 14513  1.35 Ideal     J     VS2  61.4
 28685  0.30  Good     G    VVS1  64.0
 50368  0.75 Ideal     F     SI2  59.2")
 d = read.table(tc,head=T)
 close(tc)
 grid.newpage()
 g = grid.table2(d)
 grid.ls(g)
 grid.gedit("top-head-fill-(1|3|5)", gp=gpar(fill="red"))
 grid.gedit("cells-fill-.3", gp=gpar(fill="green"))
 grid.edit("cells-label-33", label=expression(alpha),gp=gpar(col="orange"))
```

Comment: I had seen this code when looking at that page, but could not see a way to construct a character properly naming a particular cell. Did you identify that cell by deduction or by trial-and-error?

Comment: @DWin by construction :) I wrote the function to name the grobs according to their row+col index

Comment: How do we distinguish row==2, col==3 from row==3, col==2?

Comment: 23 vs 32 should do it; obviously problems would arise after 10, but the change is trivial

Comment: @Baptiste - How do I go about making this change? My dataframe has more than 10 row and it is causing problem. Can you please help?

Comment: @Neerav edit the function and add a separator between row and col indices?

Comment: @baptiste can the answer pls be updated, as the link and several functions do not work in the suggested answer.

Comment: Just found where the new link is...it should be https://raw.githubusercontent.com/baptiste/gridextra/master/inst/test/tableGrob2.r

Answer (score 1):

I think @baptiste might have swapped the rows and columns . Here I set the second row, first column equal to 2 and then construct a test and change a fill parameter. I need to put the row value second:

```
tc  = textConnection("
     carat   VeryLongWordIndeed color clarity depth
 14513  1.35 Ideal     J     VS2  61.4
 28685  2  Good     G    VVS1  64.0
 50368  0.75 Ideal     F     SI2  59.2")
 d = read.table(tc,head=T)
 close(tc)
 grid.newpage()
 g = grid.table2(d)
 grid.ls(g)
 grid.gedit("top-head-fill-(1|3|5)", gp=gpar(fill="red"))
 rc = which(d==2, arr.ind=TRUE); loc <- paste("cells-label-", rc[2], rc[1], sep="")
 rc; loc
#      row col
#28685   2   1
#[1] "cells-label-12"
 grid.edit(loc, label=expression(alpha), gp=gpar(col="orange"))
```

The "orange" color appears in the second row, first column. You may need to specify a better example that includes construction of a color palette.

Comment: The problem is that I dont need to find a particular cell but just go to the location of the cell and change the color based on the value. "cells-label..." doesnt help when you have more than 10 rows...

Comment: Heh, you don't have any rows yet. Learn to post reproducible example with sufficient complexity to represent the problem.

Answer (score 1):

@baptiste, why is it not possible to customize the table cell gpar by modifying them directly. The structure produced by 'tableGrob' seems to store these individually. For instance:

```
exTable <- tableGrob(head(iris))
exTable$lg$lgt[[42]]$gp
```

shows that the structure stores  'col' and 'cex' values for cell # 42, but changing these directly, e.g.,

```
exTable$lg$lgt[[42]]$gp$col <- "red"
```

does not seem to have any effect on the output.

```
grid.draw(exTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying this individual colouring as well. I found a solution for multiple colour filling when the table has more than 10 columns.

I mistyped the grid.gedit(...) to grid.edit(...), and then the table was filled correctly.

I don't know why, but at least it works.

If you know why it is the case, please share your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I took the code on this page [tableGrob2](http://gridextra.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/inst/tableGrob2.r) and changed the two instances of ...ii,jj... to ...ii, ".", jj... as a way of clearly separating rows and columns. That seems to solve the issue when there are more than 10 rows.